# cannot access my Django application from /api

Tags: django, kubernetes, deployment, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have deployed my django Api on kubernetes on my localmachine, windows laptop.

I did setup kubernetes deployment, LoadBalancer service and ingress file also.
But When i try to access the api using path [http://localhost/api/my-api-endpoint](https://locahost/api/my-api-endpoint) it does not work and throws an error server not found.

While i can successfully connect using just https://locahost/my-api-endpoint

**Below is my Service file and Docker file:**

```
# START Service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: peopledb-api-service
  labels:
    app: peopledb-api-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 80 #port that the service exposes
      targetPort: 8000 #port that the app is receiving requests from via the pod
  selector:
    name: peopledb-api-deployment
# END SERVICE

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: django-api-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: localhost
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /api
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: peopledb-api-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

**Docker File:**

```
FROM python:3.9.7-slim 
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /api
COPY requirements.txt /api/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /api/
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

please note that I have not included any custom nginx config files or I also did not specify any base URL in my Django app settings.

what am I doing wrong? do I need to use custom config for nginx? if yes, then what?
do I need to specify any base URL in my API URLs in Django app or Django app settings?

[image: directory structure on my pod]

**Updated Ingress config that works:**

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: django-api-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/.*
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: peopledb-api-service
            port:
              number: 80
    host: localhost
```

please note that in this updated I added Host, used regex instead of rewrite-target and also updated path with regex.

With `path: api/` ,it was throwing error "cannot match empty path in django appURLs configured." to fix this, I added prefix 'api/' in front of all of my Api endpoint
e.g.
**Before update**:

```
endoint_url = get_token
```

**After update**: `endoint_url = api/get_token`

Comment: Does the request get to the python server?

Answer (score 0):

There is misconfiguration in your `ingress` definition. `host` should be part of your block with `http`.

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: django-api-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /api
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: peopledb-api-service
            port:
              number: 80
    host: localhost
```

Please refer to [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#hostname-wildcards) doc.

Comment: I tried updating the rules and added host: localhost

requests started to reach the nginx and when I used localhost/api, this was throwing the cant match the empty path in the App config.urls
so I had to add prefix to all my API end points in django App.urls. 

It worked after these changes but I still dont know if this is the right approach to user Ingress or it is working just because i changed my API URLs in django app. I have added updated file in the question also..